# Secondary school in the US just for one month

Tags: usa, children, study

I am in the process of planning 1 or 2 month long visit to the USA, with my children presumably on J-2 visas.  One of the still open questions is, should my children attend a secondary school while there.  (Let's assume Denver, CO, as a location, although I prefer answers aimed to tackle the general question, or backed with experience from cities in general.)

**How much of a problem is incurred to the school by a pupil who attends for much less than a full school year?**  (I am thinking about various practical and regulatory effects of varying class size.  It would also be problematic to visit the school long before actually starting attendance if the school required that.)

**What's the minimum standard of fluency in English for (briefly) attending a secondary school in the US?** My children can read and understand English on a basic level, but it's likely that they'll struggle with the spoken language more than with anything else throughout the whole stay.  I view that as a good thing and as an opportunity to complement their current "academic" and "gaming" experience of the language with a little exposure to spoken, real life use of the language and of the culture.

**Should the potential language barrier factor affect how we search for a suitable school?**  I am NOT looking for instruction in a foreign (that is, non-English) language, nor for ESL education.  I am rather trying to consider factors like public vs. private school, educational system of the school, cultural diversity of the neighborhood, distance from a university campus and so on.

Comment: I believe a question like this should be asked in Expatriates and not in Travel, even if it is just for a few weeks.

Comment: @o.m. - In my initial considering Expatriates, Travel, and Academia for asking this, it seemed to me to be a match for Travel and Academia but not a match for Expatriates because it is such a short stay and actually the shortness of it is the only reason why I'm even asking this question.

Comment: @JirkaHanika while the visit is indeed short and falls under travel, the school part is generally better to be asked in expats.se. I won't vote to close, perhaps someone else can initiate that.

Comment: Purely as a comment, I wonder if, for such a short time, your kids will benefit from being in school compared with doing something else that gives them intense real-life English language exposure. Curriculum is unlikely to match what they are learning back home.

Comment: It is definitely not a match for Academia. Academia focuses on graduate education and university. Questions about undergraduate studies are off-topic there, and even more so if it's about secondary school.

Comment: @DJClayworth - Thank you for your comment.  I'll be spending most of my time with my children while my wife works on her research, and I'm looking at secondary school as a potential facet of the travel experience or opportunity for cultural immersion for the children.  I don't care that much what they will learn "academically" during the time.  I'm not an English speaker myself so I'm not the right person to pick up an American teenage accent from even if I can hopefully give them other things during the rest of the day.  But, whether they will go to school at all is undecided right now.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni are questions about the family life of academics off topic forAcademia?

Comment: @phoog Yes, if they aren't related at all to the fact that they work in a university. "As an academic, how do I install Windows 10" is off topic. This kind of questions is called [boat programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about) in the Stack Overflow culture. While an academic is more likely to embark in a 1-2 month trip to a different state than the average person, there is nothing that makes it specific.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni - point taken.

Comment: This really isn't a general country wide answerable question, as school registration requirements aren't Federal. Is Denver your locale for the entire 30 days?

Comment: [Here's a guide for you to read](http://schoolchoice.dpsk12.org/enrollment-guide/) concerning the Denver area.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni thanks for the boat programming reference.  I had somehow missed that before now.

Comment: @CGCampbell - Thank you, the guide is excellent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As someone who grew up under short international assignments, secondary schools are not easy to hop into for short stays.  The curriculums are too different and the students feel lost rather than fitting in. Home study to keep up is better from an educational perspective.

Secondary schools also tend to be more cliquish which makes fitting in challenging as well, especially if you are joining in during the second half of the school year.

There plenty of things to see and do in a major city to keep you and the kids occupied and discovering US lifestyles without school.